# Path and Name of exe file of windows terminal preview

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

What is the name of the exe file for **windows terminal preview**,
its path and command to open it?

Like for windows terminal it is `wt.exe`

Answer (score 44):

A more generic path is:

`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe`

Answer (score 35):

Check in `AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

Look for `wt.exe` or the "WindowsTerminalPreview" directory for the preview edition.

Comment: When I searched for this, my propose was to make a key shortcut, but I was not able to do so. One alternative is adding it to the taskbar and use win+<position number>

Answer (score 13):

1. Open start menu and open Windows Terminal.
2. Click `ctrl + alt + delete` to open tasks manager.
3. Look for Windows Terminal task and unfold it.
4. Find Windows Terminal, click your right mouse button, click open file location. It will navigate `WindowsTerminal.exe` automatically.
5. That's it.

On my computer WindowsTerminal is installed at `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.9.1942.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`. Note that `WindowsApps` may be hidden and restricted, you should make sure it is visible and accessable.

Comment: In my case, when unfolding `Windows Terminal` I then had to show the file location for the item named `~`. Then It is in that same folder under the name of `wt.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Helped me understand how to locate other exe files through taskmanager, and gave me the correct location for adding a Desktop shortcut

Comment: Why is even that local for the exe file so cumbersome? Does it mean that after ever app update I'll have to search for the exe file in a different location?

Answer (score 12):

Try using `where` command in `cmd`. Like this `where wt.exe`, you should get full path (mine `C:\Users\{user-name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe`

Comment: I find I need to use `where.exe wt.exe` as `where` is a standard alias for `Where-Object`.

Answer (score 8):

Usually I'd recommend that this question be moved to Super User, since it isn't programming related.  However, it's too old for that at this point.

`wt.exe` is what's known as an "Execution Alias", a "fake exe" method to open a Windows Store app (a.k.a. Metro, a.k.a. Universal, a.k.a. Modern, or whatever it's called today).

Both "Windows Terminal" and "Windows Terminal Preview" use the same `wt.exe` execution alias, since Preview is just a pre-release of the final version.

If you have both versions installed, you'll need to choose which one runs with `wt.exe` by going to "Manage App Execution Aliases" in the settings (just search for it in the Start menu).  Switch off the one you don't want to be using; switch on the one you do.

Comment: Switching **Off-and-On** _App Execution Alias_ helped me to restore the alias `wt.exe` (size 0 byte) to work (which is stored at `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe`)

Comment: (Re)installing Windows Terminal places the `wt.exe` alias in a subfolder of `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` which is not in my path. As escalator says, follow instructions in this answer and turn it off, turn it on recreates the `wt.exe` alias directly in the `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` folder which is in the path

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute wt.exe previously.

Now "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" returns the following. The system cannot find the file XXXX\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe.

The wt.exe is in this directory as expected.

However, when I search for "Windows Terminal" and open it from the start menu it opens.

I believe this behavior is due to a change in my companies security GPO governing the execution of scripts. I am not certain of this yet.

I do not yet have more details but I am digging to find out more.

Comment: I have the same problem. I had some pretty elaborate split pane setup using a custom shortcut now it is not working saying wt.exe can't be found.

Comment: It was changed after the update. Here is the path in my case: "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe/wt.exe"